# How can I prove $x^2+y^2-x-y-xy+1≥0$

Tags: inequality, quadratics, discriminant

How can I prove

> $$x^2+y^2-x-y-xy+1≥0$$

I tried $(x+y)^2-3xy-(x+y)+1≥0 \rightarrow(x+y-1)(x-y)-3xy+1≥0$ I can not continue

Answer (score 4):

> $$x^2+y^2-x-y-xy+1≥0 \Rightarrow \frac 12( 2x^2+2y^2-2x-2y-2xy+2)≥0 \Rightarrow \frac 12( x^2-2x+1+y^2-2y+1+x^2+y^2-2xy)≥0 \Rightarrow \frac 12((x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(x-y)^2)≥0$$

Comment: You want your implications to go the other way.  The way you have written it, you have assumed what you want to prove.  As all the steps are reversible, you can just turn the arrows around.

Comment: `\impliedby` $\impliedby$ would be perfect

Comment: I could not translate exactly. Could you write more clearly?

Comment: Or simply write $$x^2+y^2-x-y-xy+1=\frac12((x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(x-y)^2)\ge0$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way :$$\begin{align}x^2+y^2-x-y-xy+1&=x^2+(-1-y)x+y^2-y+1\\\\&=\left(x+\frac{-1-y}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{-1-y}{2}\right)^2+y^2-y+1\\\\&=\left(x-\frac{1+y}{2}\right)^2+\frac 34(y-1)^2\ge 0\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you calculate $\left(\frac{-1-y}{2}\right)^2+y^2-y+1$

Comment: @Zaharyas: We have $\color{red}{-}\left(\frac{-1-y}{2}\right)^2+y^2-y+1$ instead. It equals $\frac{-1-2y-y^2+4y^2-4y+4}{4}=\frac{3}{4}(y^2-2y+1)=\frac 34(y-1)^2$.

Comment: @mathlove I know this... I want to know what is the meaning? $\left(\frac{-1-y}{2}\right)^2$

Comment: @Zaharyas: It comes from $x^2+(-1-y)x=(x+\frac{-1-y}{2})^2-(\frac{-1-y}{2})^2$. In general, $x^2+2Ax=(x+A)^2-A^2$.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that
$$x^2-(y+1)x+y^2-y+1\geq0,$$ which is a quadratic inequality of $x$.

Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$(y+1)^2-4(y^2-y+1)\leq0$$ or
$$(y-1)^2\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=x^2+y^2-x-y-xy\iff x^2-x(1+y)+y^2-y-u=0$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

$$\implies(1+y)^2-4(y^2-y-u)\ge0$$

$$4u\ge3y^2-6y-1=3(y-1)^2-4\ge-4$$